# Know what derived to cast to a base class in c# with generics

Tags: c#

I am making a command handler in .NET CORE.
I have a base abstract class:

```
public abstract class ConsoleCommandBase
{ 
    public string CommandName;
    public bool FailsOnBadArgument;
    public abstract void Execute(string[] args);
}
```

And a few classes that inherit from it so

```
public class ConsoleCommand<T> : ConsoleCommandBase
    {
        private Action<T> Action;
        public ConsoleCommand(string commandName,Action<T> action)
        {

            CommandName = commandName;
            Action = action;
        }
        public override void Execute(string[] args)
        {
            //Expected Arguments are 1 so check if args has at least a length of 1
            if (args.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{CommandName} could not be executed too few arguments were present.");
                return;
            }
            Action?.Invoke(GenericConversion<T>.GetValueFromString(args[0]));
        }
    }
```

I have ConsoleCommand<T..Tn> but all of them are structured the same way.
The generic conversion class is just a simple try catch that attempts to convert the
string value to whatever T is with `(T) Convert.ChangeType(var,typeof(T))`

**Now the problem:**
All the commands are stored in a `List<ConsoleCommandBase>`
and then are converted to whatever type they where when added with if statements so:

```
if (consoleCommand is ConsoleCommand<string> command1)
{
    command1.Execute(args);
    return true;
}
```

**The problem is that this does not scale very well** for example if I use four types so [int,bool,string,float]
for my `ConsoleCommand<T>` are only 4 if statements but for `ConsoleCommand<T,T1,T2,T3>` are already over 300 if statements and it grows very rapidly.
I know there must be an easier way of doing this, because right now I can use a code generator and generate the if statements in an instant but having a 5000 lines code file does not seam to be the proper way of doing things.

Comment: Not sure why you need to check for actual type - `Execute` method is shared among all commands, i.e. `consoleCommand.Execute(args);` should work (if `consoleCommand` is `ConsoleCommandBase`), no need for `if (consoleCommand is ConsoleCommand<string> command1)`

Comment: Ok my brain is very small THANKS! Omg I'm laughing so hard. Sorry for bothering!

Comment: You should also consider using `parameter object` instead of plain list of typed arguments in your `Action`.
Then you don't have to endlessly expand with T1, T2, ... TN+1 in the future and it is easier to maintain.

Comment: Use the `.OfType<ConsoleCommand<string>>()` in the list and it will return a list of the specified derived type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a lot more functionality into your base class:

```
    public abstract class ConsoleCommandBase
    {
        public string CommandName;
        public bool FailsOnBadArgument;
        protected abstract Type[] Types { get; }
        public int TypeCount => Types.Length;
        protected ConsoleCommandBase(string commandName) => CommandName = commandName; 
        public void Execute(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != Types.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{CommandName} could not be executed too few arguments were present.");
                return;
            }

            var objects = args.Zip(Types).Select((value, type) => Convert(value, type)).ToArray();
            Execute(objects);
        }

        private object Convert(string value, Type conversionType)
        {
            //Put your conversion code here to convert the string value into the selected type
        }

        protected abstract void Execute(object[] objects);
    }
```

This leaves a lot less repetition in your child classes, but it also exposes the number of types in the child class. Executing from your `List<ConsoleCommandBase>` becomes:

```
        public void Execute(string[] args)
        {
            List<ConsoleCommandBase> list = GetYourList();
            var executer = list.First(c => c.TypeCount == args.Length);
            executer.Execute(args);
        }
```

And here is what your child classes might look like:

```
    public class ConsoleCommand<T> : ConsoleCommandBase
    {
        private readonly Action<T> _action;

        public ConsoleCommand(string commandName, Action<T> action) : base(commandName)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        protected override Type[] Types { get; } = new[] { typeof(T) };
        protected override void Execute(object[] objects)
        {
            _action?.Invoke((T)objects[0]);
        }
    }

    public class ConsoleCommand<T1,T2> : ConsoleCommandBase
    {
        private readonly Action<T1,T2> _action;

        public ConsoleCommand(string commandName, Action<T1,T2> action) : base(commandName)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        protected override Type[] Types { get; } = new[] { typeof(T1),typeof(T2) };
        protected override void Execute(object[] objects)
        {
            _action?.Invoke((T1)objects[0],(T2)objects[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **WOW**. Thanks I have a learned a lot from this :D. Thank you